# Split function in mongoldb with $ in String amount field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm trying to split my amount field(String) and remove dollar symbol, for grouping and sum of amount, but I'm getting error saying $ is not valid path

Sample Data:

```
   {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "637ac16a7c31adec64511551"
  },
  "User": "0",
  "Card": "0",
  "Year": "2002",
  "Month": "11",
  "Day": "26",
  "Time": "11:21",
  "Amount": "$379.73",
  "Use Chip": "Swipe Transaction",
  "Merchant Name": "6515854639642454768",
  "Merchant City": "Calexico",
  "Merchant State": "CA",
  "Zip": "92231.0",
  "MCC": "3066",
  "Errors?": "",
  "Is Fraud?": "No"
}
```

```
    project_cost = {
            "$project": {
            "MCC": 1,
            "cost_split": {
                "$split": [
                "$Amount", "$"
            ]
            }
        }
        }
```

Error:

```
    pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Invalid $project :: caused by :: '$' by itself is not a valid FieldPath, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "Invalid $project :: caused by :: '$' by itself is not a valid FieldPath", 'code': 16872, 'codeName': 'Location16872'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem.

The database is interpreting your delimiter (`"$"`) as the character indicating that a field is going to be expressed. Similar to how the `$` in the preceding `"$Amount"` is being processed, except this time around there are no further characters in the string. This leads to the error that you are receiving:

```
'$' by itself is not a valid FieldPath
```

To resolve the problem you can use [the `$literal` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/). That operator effectively allows us to "escape" the character by returning the value without parsing.

Your `$project` would look like this:

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "MCC": 1,
      "cost_split": {
        "$split": [
          "$Amount",
          {
            $literal: "$"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bk56KSajNjx)

---

Edit with some additional thoughts.

If you *know* that this field always contains a string with the `$` character as a prefix, another approach would be using [the `$substrBytes` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes):

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "MCC": 1,
      "cost_split": {
        "$substr": [
          "$Amount",
          1,
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
```

In either case you will need an additional wrapper to get it to a number for subsequent summation, e.g.:

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "MCC": 1,
      "cost_split": {
        "$toDouble": {
          "$substrBytes": [
            "$Amount",
            1,
            -1
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Long term, it might be worth storing the data as a number directly. It is often less expensive to format a numeric value for display than it is to convert it for querying and/or computation.